# Handlebars escape single charicter

Tags: handlebars.js

I am having an issue with handlebar's escaping a single {, I want the output to be

with a context of { var : "Some Value" }

I would like an output of

```
{Some Value}
```

I have tried

```
{ {{var}} } compiles to { Some Value } ( I need no space )
\{{{var}}} which compiles to {{var}}
\{{{{var}}\}} which compiles to {{Some Value\}}
{{{{raw}}}}{{{{{/raw}}}}{{var}}{{{{raw}}}}}{{{{/raw}}}} Throws an error
```

any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars supports whitespace trim with `~`. Try

```
{ {{~var~}} }
```